# PNG Image as Button

Tags: javascript, html, button, png

I am trying to set an image in my assets as a button, and for the most part, have it working. The image is a PNG.

Here is my HTML code for the button:

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "start()"> <img src = "assets/site/start-button.png"> </button>
```

Here is the PNG image: [image: click me]

Here is what I see: [image: click me pt 2]

How do I make the white part of the button go away? I think (not completely sure if this is the case -- if not, could someone please explain what is happening?) that the button is encasing the image, like it does text, instead of simply having the image as a button. How do I change this? I want it to only show the PNG image, nothing else.

EDIT: I do not have any css for the button. Do I need to add anything?

Comment: This can probably be done by modifying the stylesheet (CSS).

Comment: How so? As in, would I try to make the button invisible/transparent? I'm unsure how to do that if that is the case.

Comment: Please include your CSS in the question. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the image from the button, and instead setting it as a background image in css, while remove the default button styles. Working example:

```js
function start() {
  console.log('start');
}
```

```css
.button {
  background: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png') no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="start()" class="button" />
```

If you are unfamiliar with css, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started

Comment: I tried this code, but no buttons show up. Is it perhaps supposed to say "<button name ="button"...etc"?

Comment: I added it to a code snippet you can run, and you can see it working in the output.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried the code, and it seems to work. I think the image is there, but it is incredibly small (it doesn't include the whole image, only one corner).. Is there a way to increase the size of the button?

Comment: Final update: I got it! Your code worked, and I just added a padding section to the button's CSS code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to remove all styles from the button, such as its background-color, border etc..

You can remove the browser's default styles by adding the CSS property `apperance: none;`

I'd recommend using an anchor tag, instead of a button if you're wrapping an image.

Comment: What is an anchor tag? Would it allow me to call a function on click as a button does?

Comment: An anchor tag is a `<a href="...">` tag

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll see if that works. Thank you!